# How to compare lines in a single file line by line and append the output to the same file

Tags: awk, sed, csv, echo

I have a file `abc.csv` that has the below contents.

```
a6caa290d03ae75dd5f3bf9214f0b523;CO.jar,a6caa290d03ae75dd5f3bf9214f0b523;CO.jar,
a1a5bf1547f50feea4120290343f89e4;Common.jar,a1a5bf1547f50feea4120290343f89e4;Common.jar,
1264897ea44d85c3f0dba127ff02f514;DA.jar,1264897ea44d85c3f0dba127ff02f514;DA.jar,
e77834d4ba2a4193b94fee9470a458a4;FW.jar,e77834d4ba2a4193b94fee9470a458a4;FW.jar,
```

I need to read the file line by line and compare the values that is before and after `,` If both are equal, write `SUCCESS` at the same end of the line else `FAILURE` at the same end of the line.

I tried the below.

```
for I in `cat abc.csv`
do
   VAR1=`echo $I | awk -F"," {'print ${1}'}
   VAR2=`echo $I | awk -F"," {'print ${2}'}
   if [ ${1} == ${2} ]
   then
       ..
   fi
done
```

I am not sure how to add `SUCCESS` or `FAILURE` at the end of each line.
Any idea how can this be achieved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
for I in `cat abc.csv`
do
        var1=`echo "$I" | awk -F "," '{print $1}'`
        var2=`echo "$I" | awk -F "," '{print $2}'`
        if [ $var1 == $var2 ]; then
               sed -i 's/'$var1','$var2'/'$var1','$var2',SUCCESS/' abc.csv
        else
               sed -i 's/'$var1','$var2'/'$var1','$var2',FAIL/' abc.csv
        fi

done
```

And one liner:

```
 echo "`awk -F"," '{ if($1 == $2)  {print $1","$2",SUCCESS"} else {print $1","$2",FAILURE"} }' abc.csv`" > abc.csv
```

Comment: You are calling `sed` and `awk` twice for each row in the data. This is extremely inefficient. Both `sed` and `awk` could be used once over the whole file to do this.

Comment: @Kusalananda You are right... i was tired to answer on PO's way. Now updated with oneliner as well.

Comment: But the `echo` is not needed... oh I see what you are playing at. Is that guaranteed to not truncate the file before `awk` is called?

Comment: @Kusalananda OP wants to edit the file, i'm using this way to do awk inline. PLz share if there is any other way of awk inline.

Comment: I would probably do `awk ... file >newfile && mv newfile file` but you may also do `awk -i inplace ... filename` with GNU `awk` (specifically) to do in-place editing.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it all in awk. awk runs its script for each line in its input

The awk statement `print x y` prints the expressions `x` and `y` right next to each other, with no blank or field separator between them.

The awk expression `a ? b : c` means "if `a` is true then `b` else `c`".

```
awk -F"," '{ print $0 (($1 == $2) ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILURE") }' < abc.csv
```

Comment: Hi. That awk works. But that doesn’t write into the same file. It just prints as output on screen.

Comment: @sabarishjackson Redirect output to new file, then `mv` the new file over the original file. This is standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
sed -r 's/^(.*,)\1/& SUCCESS/; t;  s/$/ FAILURE/;' file
```

Make sure your input files loses the DOS line terminators (`<CR>` = \r = 0x0D = ^M) before running this.
If happy with what you see, redirect to a result file

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed` (the `t` command needs a label if ended with `;` in standard `sed`):

```
$ sed '/^\([^,]*,\)\1/s/$/SUCCESS/;t;s/$/FAILURE/' file
a6caa290d03ae75dd5f3bf9214f0b523;CO.jar,a6caa290d03ae75dd5f3bf9214f0b523;CO.jar,SUCCESS
a1a5bf1547f50feea4120290343f89e4;Common.jar,a1a5bf1547f50feea4120290343f89e4;Common.jar,SUCCESS
1264897ea44d85c3f0dba127ff02f514;DA.jar,1264897ea44d85c3f0dba127ff02f514;DA.jar,SUCCESS
e77834d4ba2a4193b94fee9470a458a4;FW.jar,e77834d4ba2a4193b94fee9470a458a4;FW.jar,SUCCESS
```

An example where two lines generates `FAILURE`:

```
$ sed '/^\([^,]*,\)\1/s/$/SUCCESS/;t;s/$/FAILURE/' file
a6caa290d03ae75dd5f3bf9214f0b523;CO.jar,a6caa290d03ae75dd5f3bf9214f0b523;CO.jar,SUCCESS
1a5bf1547f50feea4120290343f89e4;Common.jar,a1a5bf1547f50feea4120290343f89e4;Common.jar,FAILURE
1264897ea44d85c3f0dba127ff02f514;DA.jar,1264897ea44d85c3f0dba127ff02f514;DA.jar,SUCCESS
77834d4ba2a4193b94fee9470a458a4;FW.jar,e77834d4ba2a4193b94fee9470a458a4;FW.jar,FAILURE
```

The `sed` script with annotations:

```
/^\([^,]*,\)\1$/s/$/SUCCESS/;   # this lines looks like XXX,XXX,
                                # add SUCCESS at the end of the line
t;                              # branch to end of script if last s command did something
s/$/FAILURE/                    # add FAILURE at the end of the line
```

To perform an in-place editing with GNU `sed`, use the above command but with `sed -i` in place of `sed`.

---

Explanation of `/^\([^,]*,\)\1/`:  If this regular expression matches, then the substitution following it will be performed and will add `SUCCESS` at the end of the line.  The regular expression matches a string at the start of a line up to and including the first comma. It then tries to match this same string *again* immediately following the first. The `\1` will reference the string matched by `\(...\)`.